# Managing the context of NSPersistentContainer

Tags: swift, core-data, cloudkit, nspersistentstore

I have a class that manages my `NSPersistentContainer` for my CloudKit/CoreData. In a view to access its contents or update I use an `@EnvironmentObject` and call the methods and it works perfectly.

The problem is now I need to use it in a class where I can't access the environment object. So I added a shared property to the my class to access it. It works fine but the published variables don't seem to update on my views when triggered by the class.

A simple example looks as followed:

My Datacontroller:

```
class DataController: ObservableObject {

    static let shared = DataController()
    
    //Coredatastack would be here
    
    let container: NSPersistentContainer
    
    @Published var remaining: Int = 0
    @Published var today: DayProgress? = nil

    func getRemaining() {
        remaining = Int((today?.dailyGoal ?? 0) - (today?.currDailyTotal ?? 0))
    }
```

If I call `getRemaining()` anytime after updating the values of the published variable today in a view, then anywhere the environmentObject remaining is accessed will update.

But in a class if I use `Datacontroller.shared.getRemaining()`, it will not update the published variable remaining on the view. I assume this is because im working with different instances of the `Datacontroller()` but im not sure how to solve this. Thanks for any hints or tips.

Note: The class that is triggers the updates the is triggered from outside the app (shortcut) and I have a function that calls `getRemainder()` anytime the app opens

Comment: This needs more information in form of a [mre]. If you use a shared instance create a private initializer to take care you don´t accidentally initialize it anywhere it shouldn´t.

Comment: Ok thanks, I will try and create an example.